# Why does my UILabel start counting backward at 2 billion?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, int, uilabel

I have a `UILabel` in my iPhone app simulator. It displays a coin count and I have an action that adds 1 hundred million to the count. I want the number to keep going up but for some reason once the count hits 2 billion, it adds a minus sign and starts counting down, then counts back up to 2 billion and back down again and so on.

I want to be able to display a much greater number of digits ie trillions and so on... Does anyone know what's going on with this and how to fix it so the label digits will keep going up as high as I want.

I'm using Xcode and Interface Builder and running through the simulator. I'm storing the number in a `int` variable, if that matters.

Comment: Please use upper case letters next time where appropriate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You store your coin count in an `int`, that's the problem. A 4 byte `int` can't store numbers higher than **2,147,483,647**. If you add 1 to 2,147,483,647 you will get −2,147,483,648, which is the smallest possible `int`.

If you want to store bigger numbers you have to use a `long` which can store numbers between −(2^63) and 2^63−1 (or −9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807).

See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_%28computer_science%29) for additional details.

Comment: That makes sense but I just tried long and long long, and the same thing happened. Anything else I should check. Is it possible that it's my computer or the simulator?

Comment: How to you convert your number to a string when putting it into the label?

Comment: I guess you are using [format specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html)? In that case you have to add an `l` or `ll` before the `d` to specify a `long` or `long long`. Otherwise it will be just converted to an `int`. `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ld", coins];`

Answer (score 2):

This is occurring because, as @DrummerB pointed out, your `int` variable only has enough bits to store integral values in the range of `-2,147,483,647` to `2,147,483,647`. The reason this gets "reset" or "rolls over" back to a negative has to do with how computers store data, which is in binary.

For example, if you had an 8-bit integer (otherwise known as a `byte`) can store integral values from `0` to `255` if it is unsigned (meaning it can only store positive values) and `-127` to `127` if it is signed (meaning it can store negative numbers). When an integer reaches its max value, it is represented in memory by all ones as you see here with the unsigned value `255`:

`255 = 11111111`

So the maximum number that can be stored in an 8-bit `int` (`byte`) is `255`. If you add `1` to this value, you end up flipping all the `1` values so that they are zeroes and since storing the value `256` would require a 9th bit you lose the 9th bit entirely and the integer value will appear to "roll over" to the minimum value.

Now.. As I stated above, the result of the addition above yields the value `256`, but we only have 8 bits of storage in our integer so the most significant bit (9th bit) is lost. So you can picture it kinda like this with the pipes `|` marking your storage area:

```
            only 8 bits of storage total
            v
 255 = 0|11111111|
+  1 = 0|00000001|
-------------------
 256 = 1|00000000|
       ^
       9th bit is lost
```

In an `unsigned int`, the same is true, however the first bit is used to determine if the value is negative so you gain signing but you lose 1 bit of storage, resulting in your only having enough space to store the values `0` to `127` and 1 bit for signing.

Now that we understand what's going on, it should be noted that iOS is, at the time of this writing, a 32-bit operating system and while it *can* handle larger integers you probably don't want to use them all over the place as it's not optimized to work with these values.

If you just want to increase the range of values you can store in this variable, I would recommend changing it to an `unsigned int`, which can be done using the `NSUInteger` typedef.